# pip install dependency installs older version of a library

Tags: pip, dependencies

My app has a requirements file that looks something like this:

```
somelibrary==2
otherlib==1.5
```

Now the problem is that `otherlib` contains in its setup file `somelibrary` as dependency and what happens is that pip first installs `somelibrary` in version 2 as required by my file, but later installs an older version because of `otherlib` which hides the version of `somelibrary` that my app needs and that also works for `otherlib`. I checked the setup.py file of `otherlib` and it does not specify a version for `somelibrary`. How can I stop pip from installing the older version on top of the newer one?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].